# In P.C. Hodgell's Kencyrath books, is Bane dead?

Tags: kencyrath

In P.C. Hodgell's *Godstalk*, Jame learns that an amoral character in the book, Bane, is her half brother. After kissing her (and biting her lip down to the muscles in the process), he shoves her into a room and faces an angry mob for her. It's implied that he was flayed alive on the Mercy Seat (Jame sees the bloody chair later on and a few flashbacks and mystic visions suggest it), but partway through the book, she also learns that Bane had given his soul to one of the priests for safe keeping, a process which traditionally renders the Highborn very, very hard to kill. He also shows up as a possessing shade two books later to haunt Jame, something fairly unprecedented in this world.

> "Wait a minute," she said again. "How do you know these things, Ashe? 'Haunts know what concerns haunts,' you said once. Is Bane dead?"
>
> "His state is . . . peculiar. Did you know . . . that the Brandan Matriarch thinks he is . . . a projection of the nemesis in you?"

So, my assumption for some time was the same as Jame, that he was killed at the Mercy Seat and something about the kiss and the blood (it's later revealed that Jame is a rather potent blood binder) as well as possibly the absence of his soul, that led to Bane coming back as he did, but Hodgell asked on her Livejournal whether anyone knew if she'd explicitly stated that Bane had died. My re-reads haven't come up with anything, but I know that there are people more skilled than I am at finding details in books. Anyone have good textual proof showing that Bane did or did not die?

Just to complicate things, Hodgell later posted [her musings on Bane](http://tagmeth.livejournal.com/62149.html) which indicates that she's not even certain anymore if Jame was right that his disembodied soul was indeed the Lower Town Monster:

> I dunno, though:  one’s instinct is that the Lower Town Monster is Bane’s corrupted, detached soul.  That’s certainly the way I’ve presented it.  It’s possible, though, that the situation is more complicated than Jame thinks in God Stalk.  She turns out to be wrong about a number of things re: gods and demons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, [the word from the author](http://tagmeth.livejournal.com/62149.html) is that he is not truly dead (emphasis mine):

> What [Bane] really wants is an honorable death.  Ironically, **any death will be hard to get while his body and soul remain separated**.  When/if they reunite, will he become horrible, like Dorian Gray?  Something dramatic will happen to him, anyway.  That won’t be until near the end.

That does still leave it ambiguous as to whether his body was killed, but the fact that she discusses a possible eventual reuniting of body and soul suggests that it was not destroyed (unless she's going with the interpretation that having a drop of blood present is sufficient to consist of the "body" as per a recent plot reveal about the death banners).

As an update, this was resolved in *By Demon's Possessed*.

> “Hello,” said Bane.
>  His clothes were cruelly slashed, held together with cobwebs and clotted blood. His thin face was ashen under a tangle of dark, dusty hair. Blood continued to trickle down his side to pool at his feet.
>
>  Everything Jame had thought she would say to him at this moment vanished. “You look awful,” she heard herself blurt out instead. “What happened to you?”
>
>  He laughed. “Have you noticed that every time we meet . . .”.
>
>  ". . . someone ends up bleeding.”.
>  “This time,” he said, “it happens to be me. What occurred? That is a very good question. I remember clearly, up to a point. So, no doubt, do you. They came for me in the Sirdan’s palace. I was stabbed, oh, so many times.” He surveyed himself with wonder and fastidious distain. “Any one of these wounds might have proved fatal but then, of course, I didn’t have access to my soul. As it is, they don’t even seem to have closed. Then my dear guild brothers took me to the Mercy Seat. I was to be flayed alive, I believe. Instead, the earth opened up and swallowed the Seat, with me still on it. Was that your doing?”

Comment: According to the author, he's back as of book 9,and she's "still trying to make out his final fate". She has also stated that there are about 2-3 books left.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that Pat will not reread her earlier books ever.  Apparently it leads to her being overly self-critical and sets off a bout of self-hatred and depression, if I remember right.

I don't think it was ever stated definitively what happened.  Bane's biting kiss was intended to blood-bind Jame; he has also inherited the trait, and probably used it to make the boys he tortured and killed compliant to his wishes.  However Jame, being full-blood Knorth and with (one presumes) two blood-binder parents, has the stronger blood and it blood-bound him.

We do know these things:

1. His soul was not in his body (but instead was in the Lower Town Monster)
2. His body could not technically die until his soul returned to it
3. Jame and Patches both told Dalis-sar and Gorgo his true name as they believed it to be, allowing them to destroy the demon
4. Blood-binding can force obedience even after death
5. His body was pretty much torn apart on the Mercy Seat.

My guess (and I think it can only be a guess) is that his soul was freed from the demon but did not re-enter his body, since it was driven by the blood-binding to follow and serve Jame.  His body may technically not have died but was, I suspect, destroyed, and was only alive in a sort of mystical sense.

And now he's in a cave tomb until released, commanded to guard the Knife and Book and permitted to consume and kill anyone who tries to get in who isn't Jame or possibly Ashe.  Sounds like a tedious life but I guess the compulsion of blood-binding makes him do it.

What I am wondering is whether his guardianship can prevent the Book or Knife escaping if *they* want to.  It's clear that the Kencyr ritual objects are somewhat "alive" and have minds of their own.  The Knife will likely seek out Jame, the Book Torisen; and I wonder what the Cloak will do if Kindrie goes looking for it.  It's still somewhere in the Master's House, it seems.